# Symfony 1.4 and doctrine autoincrement instead of auto_increment

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, yaml

I have a weird problem.

Here's my yaml:

`Request:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, notnull: true }`

When i perform a symfony `doctrine:build --all --no-confirmation` inside my `BaseRequest.class.php` there's an error during the declaration of my id field:

`$this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             'length' => 4,
             ));`

As you can see it should be auto_increment but instead it's autoincrement so i have to manually change this after each build.

Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: what exactly makes you say it should be `auto_increment` instead of `autoincrement`? I have this declaration in one of my models, with `autoincrement`, and in MySQL, I can see `auto_increment`, it works fine.

Comment: It's fine in mySQL but when i try to save my item i get "Couldn't get last insert identifier" and when i change to auto_increment it works.

Comment: after inserting a new row, what does `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` return in mysql?

Comment: It returns 0, i'm not sure why.

Comment: did you try in both cases? Is there any difference? Also, is there any difference when you do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table` ?

Comment: SHOW CREATE returns ``id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` and it seems like it uses InnoDB, maybe that's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

not exactly answer to your question, but you don't need to specify id column for your entities, doctrine does that automatically

Comment: Yup but i had the "Couldn't get last insert identifier" problem so i had to find a workaround